# Page title as set in admin - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, title

I'm trying to make a breadcrumbs area that contains the homepage name first. The problem is the name is in another language. How can I get the custom name that is set in the pages area of the admin.

**Edit:** Thank you Zameer.
Also I found these 2 lines:

```
$page_object = get_queried_object();
$page_id     = get_queried_object_id();
```

that help you find the page ID and a few other informations about the page you are in.

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel? https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/breadcrumbs/

Comment: Thank you. But I would still like to find out how you can get the page name, just in case I need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want title of a particular page using id then use

```
<?php echo get_the_title($ID); ?>
```

This function will return the title (as set in the pages area) of a post for a given post ID.

Comment: This returns the name of the current page. I want to return the Homepage name when I am on another page (for example Projects).

Comment: Pass home page ID and it will return you the homepage name. Simple.

Comment: Ok. I had problems finding out the page IDs for different pages. But I found something that helps you get the page ID. I will paste it in my original post, maybe it will help someone else out. Coupled with it, your answer is perfect, thank you.